# Substring and invert in SAS

Tags: sas, substr

I have a SAS data set with observations like this:

```
Abatucci Pierre*L'entrée au château*1000*1*75*91
Agneessens Edouard*Jeune femme*6000*1*40*32*5
```

where * is the field separator. How can I create a new variable that has First_name_letter+" "+Surname like this:

```
Abatucci Pierre ----> P Abatucci
Agneessens Eduard ----> E Agneessens
```

Comment: Which database? You gotta give us more info.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
data name;
infile cards dlm='*';
length name name2 $35 entree $35;
input name entree calories portion cost weight;
name2=substr(scan(name,2,' '),1,1) ||' '||scan(name,1,' ');
datalines;
Abatucci Pierre*L'entrée au château*1000*1*75*91
Agneessens Edouard*Jeune femme*6000*1*40*32*5
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this is with the Perl regular expression functionality that is built into SAS:

```
data names;
 set dataset;
 name = prxchange('s/(\w)\w* (\w+)/$2 $1/', -1, name);
run;
```

(I'm assuming that the *s in your question are actually field separators, because your other recent question asked how to deal with that.)

The expression `(\w)\w* (\w+)` causes the first letter of the first word of `name` and the second word of `name` to be put into variables `$1` and `$2`. The rest of the command tells SAS to substitute `$2 $1` for this variable.